# Ошибка "[SSL: CA_MD_TOO_WEAK] ca md too weak (_ssl.c:3862)')" при использовании requests с сертификатом

Tags: python-3.x, requests, ssl, openssl, python-3.10

Есть [у меня скрипт для работы, который по сертификату ходит на корпоративный сайт](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5bfa692c68ac19d2a44f8bfc3f2b28cb9a33b7a0/current_job_report/get_user_and_deviation_hours.py#L35):

```
PEM_FILE_NAME = str(DIR / 'ipetrash.pem')

headers = {
    'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,
}

rs = requests.post(URL, data=data, headers=headers, cert=PEM_FILE_NAME, verify=False)
```

Но он перестал работать. Подозреваю, что причина в обновлении ssl в python3.10

**Как его починить?**

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 416, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 418, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CA_MD_TOO_WEAK] ca md too weak (_ssl.c:3862)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.compassplus.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pa-reports/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(398, '[SSL: CA_MD_TOO_WEAK] ca md too weak (_ssl.c:3862)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\PycharmProjects\SimplePyScripts\current_job_report\get_user_and_deviation_hours.py", line 169, in <module>
    name, deviation_hours = get_user_and_deviation_hours()
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\PycharmProjects\SimplePyScripts\current_job_report\get_user_and_deviation_hours.py", line 159, in get_user_and_deviation_hours
    content = get_report_context()
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\PycharmProjects\SimplePyScripts\current_job_report\get_user_and_deviation_hours.py", line 74, in get_report_context
    return _send_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\PycharmProjects\SimplePyScripts\current_job_report\get_user_and_deviation_hours.py", line 58, in _send_data
    rs = session.post(URL, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ipetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.compassplus.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pa-reports/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(398, '[SSL: CA_MD_TOO_WEAK] ca md too weak (_ssl.c:3862)')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло [это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580908/5909792) через создание `TLSAdapter` от `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter`, в котором устанавливается настройка `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1`. А эта настройка снизит уровень безопасности до того уровня, что использовался в старой версии openssl

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ef9e330be33e9bd2d6669d3813a6c1a862f0d74f/current_job_report/get_user_and_deviation_hours.py#L28)

```
class TLSAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.set_ciphers('DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1')
        kwargs['ssl_context'] = ctx
        return super(TLSAdapter, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)


URL = 'https://jira.compassplus.ru/pa-reports/'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0'
PEM_FILE_NAME = str(DIR / 'ipetrash.pem')


session = requests.session()
session.cert = PEM_FILE_NAME
session.mount('https://', TLSAdapter())
session.headers['User-Agent'] = USER_AGENT

rs = session.post(URL, data=data)
```